# Square the number pattern using for loop

Tags: python, pattern-matching

Write a for loop to iterate through the list A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]. Square each element of the list in one by one fashion and print them. After the end of the iteration, print - "The sequence has ended"

```
1
4
9
16
25
36
The sequence has ended
```

Comment: What does this have to do with pattern matching? This is just a simple `for item in A` loop.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Ok. Did you try anything yet?

Comment: `list(map(lambda x:print(x**2),A)) and print("The sequence has ended")`

Answer (score 1):

The code for your question can be written as:

```
for i in A:
     print(i*i)
print("The sequence has ended")
```

Explanation:

The for i in A line helps iterate through the list A and the next line print(i*i) prints the square of the number.
The last line prints the last statement.

Hope it helps...